# generating jasper reports using ireport designer tool

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I generated PDF report using ireport designer tool. Upto here it is fine.

My question is :

If there is no data in the database then it is showing blank pdf page. At this time how can i show "No data found for this request" in pdf?

Comment: are you using parameters or fields in your report ?

Comment: Show us the code you did for printing the data when available..

Comment: i am using parameters

Comment: File reportFile = new File(application.getRealPath("report.jasper"));Map<String,Object> parameters = new HashMap<String,Object>();
             parameters.put("faculty_createdby", loginUtil.getUser_name());
                       
             byte[] bytes = JasperRunManager.runReportToPdf(reportFile.getPath(), parameters, con);
  
             response.setContentType("application/pdf");
             response.setContentLength(bytes.length);
             ServletOutputStream outStream = response.getOutputStream();
             outStream.write(bytes, 0, bytes.length);

Answer (score 1):

There is a property of the template WhenNoDataType.

Just set it to WhenNoDataType: AllSectionsNoDetail.

This will have the template(static fields) but no dynamic data from database.

If you just want to print some message than you will have to change the design up a bit. You would need to place a condition at the beginning of your report to check if data is coming from database, and act accordingly.

Comment: There is no need to place a condition in your report. Jasper will do  this automatically if you use the `noData` section.

Comment: Ya but what if someone wants to display a message only when there is no data coming from database? How will you do that?

Comment: That is exactly what the `noData` section will do. If the query is successful but the result set contains 0 rows, the `noData` section (and only that section) is shown.

Comment: Can you give me some working link to some eg. using no data section.

Comment: If you take a look at my answer, you will see I include a working example that I created in iReport 5.0.0. The explanation of the band is on page 109 here: http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/JasperReports-Ultimate-Guide-3.pdf

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show none of the content of your report when there is no data (no title, headers, footers, etc.) then you should add a `noData` band to your report and put the message there. Then change the `whenNoDataType` report parameter to `NoDataSection`.

From the *JasperReports Ultimate Guide*:

> If the `<noData>` section is defined in the report template, and if the data source is empty, then the `<noData>` section will be the only one taken into account at fill time

Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" 
        name="report1" 
        whenNoDataType="NoDataSection">

    <pageHeader>
        <band height="20">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Page Header]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </pageHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="20">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Detail]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </detail>
    <pageFooter>
        <band height="20">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Page Footer]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </pageFooter>
    <noData>
        <band height="20">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="555" height="20"/>
                <text><![CDATA[No data found for this request]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </noData>
</jasperReport>
```

Comment: Thanq so much Mr. GenericJon

Comment: Mr. Jon, i have some doubts in 3D Bar chart, 1. if it is single record in the database then bar plot is showing full width in the bar chart. how can we set width? if the more records are there then it will be stretched automatically.  2. How can i show only numerics on Y-axis and vertical title on Y-axis

Comment: @Surendra You should open new questions for these issues.